# Cant get js values to link to HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently working on a timed quiz application and got a majority of the functionality working. But, when I went to test it I noticed the question element I set up in the HTML wasn't changing with the question objects I defined in the js file. The two files are linked together correctly, but I can't figure out where I went wrong. Tbh after looking at this for hours a fresh set of eyes would really come in handy.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="game" class="justify-center">
        <div id="hud">
            <div class="hud-item">
                <!-- container desc -->
                <p id="container-text" class="hud-prefix">
                    Question:
                </p>
                <!-- timer function -->
                <div id="timer">

                </div>
                <!-- end of timer -->
            </div>
            <div class="hud-item">
                <p class="hud-prefix">
                    Score:
                </p>
                <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
                    0
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1 id="question">What is the answer?</h1>
        <!-- making possible answers to given question -->
        <div class="choice-container">
            <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
            <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p>
        </div>
        <!-- making possible answers to given question -->
        <div class="choice-container">
            <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
            <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
        </div>
        <!-- making possible answers to given question -->
        <div class="choice-container">
            <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
            <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
        </div>
        <!-- making possible answers to given question -->
        <div class="choice-container">
            <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
            <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/script.js"></script>
```

Here is my JavaScript file:

```
const question = $('#question');
const choices = Array.from($('.choice-text'));
const scoreText = $('#score');

//defining let var which values will change throughout the game
let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswers = true;
let score = 0;
let questionCounter = 0;
let availableQustions = [];

//defining list of potential questions to be called apon by currentQuestions
let questions = [
    {
        question: 'What types of variables can you define?',
        choice1: 'var',
        choice2: 'let',
        choice3: 'const',
        choice4: 'all of the above',
        answer: 'all of the above'
    },
// question 1 ^^^^
    {
        question: 'How would you store an item to local storage?',
        choice1: 'localStorage.getItem()',
        choice2: 'localStorage.setItem()',
        choice3: 'localStorage.store()',
        choice4: 'localStorage.setLocal()',
        answer: 'localStorage.setItem()'
   },
// question 2 ^^^^
 ]
 console.log(questions)

//start game functionality and needed var
const SCORE_POINTS = 100;
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 10;

startGame = () => {
questionCounter = 0;
score = 0;
availableQustions = [...questions];
getNewQuestion();
}

//get new question function supplies new q when previous gets answered
getNewQuestion = () => {
     if(availableQustions.length === 0 || questionCounter > MAX_QUESTIONS) {
     localStorage.setItem('mostRecentScore', score)

     return window.location.assign('/end.html')
}

questionCounter++

//making random question appear
const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQustions.length)
currentQuestion = availableQustions[questionIndex]
question.innerHTML = currentQuestion.question
//was originally choices.array.forEach
choices.forEach((choice)=> {
    const number = choice.dataset['number'];
    choice.innerText = currentQuestion['choice' + number];
});

availableQustions.splice(questionIndex, 1);

acceptingAnswers = true;
}

choices.forEach(choice => {
choice.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (!acceptingAnswers) return

    acceptingAnswers = false
    const selectedChoice = e.target
    const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset['number']

    let classToApply = selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? 'correct' : 'incorrect'
    //if answer is correct add 100 to score
    if (classToApply === 'correct') {
        incrementScore(SCORE_POINTS)
    }

    selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply)

    setTimeout(() => {
        selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply)
        getNewQuestion();
    }, 1000)
  })
  });

    //increment score funt and calling start game
     incrementScore = num => {
     score += num
     scoreText.innerText = score
}

startGame();
```

I originally had ten questions but I deleted the other 8 because of stacks code to normal text ratio.

The problem that is happening is the questions aren't toggling red and green for correct and wrong answers. and the questions aren't displaying on the #question HTML element.

Heres the CSS for the correct and wrong bits

```
.correct {
   background-color: green;
   border: green 4px solid;
}
/* will change wrong answer color to red */
.wrong {
   background-color: red;
   border: red 4px solid;
}
```

Comment: The if statement in `getNewQuestion` has an opening curly bracket but no closing one, unless that's just the formatting in which case you should improve it.

Comment: The if statement has a closing curly bracket, right after the return function

Comment: Please improve the formatting in your code then. That curly bracket looks like it's closing the anonymous function.

Comment: sorry i had to manually go and indent everything so thats why it looks wonky